# How to handle non-English words (words of Arabic, Spanish and Urdu) in escape/encodeURI function of Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, csv

In my application, I am converting **json** data to **CSV** and generating a **CSV** file.As the application is supporting **MUI** so the **JSON** data is also in multiple languages like **English**, **Arabic**, **Urdu** and **Spanish**.I am using **escape** function of **javascript** as following:

var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);

here **CSV** contains the data in **CSV** formate.This is working fine if the data is in **English** language, but if it contains the words of other langauges it is converting them in **hexadecimal** formate which is not human readable.When I don't use this **escape** function, the data is fine(as there are no **hexadecimal** formate of **Arabic** or other language words) but then there is no new line in the **CSV** file, and it is showing up one long line containing all the data.I also tried other methods like **encodeURI/encodeURIComponent** but got the same results.Can somebody please guide me here that how I can handle the words of other languages in **escape** funtion OR is there any alternative way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Translate's Javascript API.
since you have not share your code, you can consider below my example and modify the function as per your requirement.

```
<p id="some">Hello</p>
<input id="trans" value="Translate" type="button">

<script>
   $('#trans').click(function() {
     google.language.translate($('#some').html(), 'en', 'fr', function(result) {
         $('#some').html(result.translation);
     });
   });
</script>
```

You will need to load the js library in your page's HEAD section in order to use the API.

Url to read : https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/?csw=1

Comment: are you suggesting to translate non-English(Arabic, Urdu, Spanish) words in English language if I fully understood? If yes, then in my case I need non-English(Arabic, Urdu, Spanish) words same as they written in there native languages.I don't want to translate them into any other language.Please correct me if I misunderstood you.Thanks.

Comment: No, i had given a code which translate english context into non-englished based on language code provided. e.g in my code it will convert to french. also can you confirm when you were using encoding were you following below syntax only : unescape(encodeURIComponent(urMessage))